# how to stop click events of checked item in navigation drawer activity using in multiple activities

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

here i used basic navigation view provided by android studio

```
 navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.getMenu().getItem(1).setChecked(true);

    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
           /* // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
            int id = item.getItemId();*/
            //Check and un-check menu item if they are checkable behaviour

            switch (item.getItemId()) {


                case R.id.nav_camera: {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TabbedActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                }
                case R.id.nav_gallery: {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "youclicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;

                }
                /* else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

                } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

                } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

                } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

                }*/
            }

             DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
             drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

even though i'm checking the second item it was responding to clicks how to stop that
please help me i'm facing this problem since yesterday

[image: see in image how i'm getting problem here]

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu (Menu menu){
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);

        MenuItem myItem = menu.findItem(R.id.myId); //here your menu ids
        myItem.setEnabled(false);

    return true;  
}
```

> Prepare the Screen's standard options menu to be displayed. This is
>   called right before the menu is shown, every time it is shown. You can
>   use this method to efficiently enable/disable items or otherwise
>   dynamically modify the contents.

Comment: @vinay  Try this let me  know

Answer (score 0):

Comment these id's which one you don't want to click like this :-

```
case R.id.nav_camera: {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TabbedActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                }
                case R.id.nav_gallery: {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "youclicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;

                }
```

Comment: @ Abhinav Gupta the menu which i'm used is checkboxes once it was checked i don't want click events to work on that option

Comment: navigationView.getMenu().getItem(1).setChecked(true);  here are you using check box?

Comment: navigationView.getMenu().getItem(1).setChecked(false); do this it may be work for you

Comment: sorry this is not the answer

Comment: @vinay Then what you want...Abhinav Gupta he is saying correct ,`navigationView.getMenu().getItem(1).setChecked(false);` This will work

Answer (score 0):

This way you can check the last item and the current item is the same or not

```
private int prevId = -1;

public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {            
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (prevId == -1 || prevId != id) {
        // Do event handling on each item.
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: i dont want click event to happen on selected item

Comment: on checked item i dont want click event to happen

Comment: I see. then when you click any item on the navigation, save the id of the selected item. next time you click any item on the navigation, check if it is already clicked using the id.